# Plotting multiple data in a data frame at fixed column intervals with corresponding legend in one single plot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have a data frame `x3` of 30 columns generated using the following codes, I would like to plot in a single plot the first column to be x axis and y-axis should be columns 5,10,15,20,25 and 30.

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- x^3
z <- y-20
s <- z/3
t <- s*6
q <- s*y
x1 <- cbind(x,y,z,s,t,q)
x2 <- cbind(x1,x1*5)
x3 <- cbind(x1,x1*5,x2*2,x1+2)
x3 <- data.frame(x3)
```

To plot multiple y-data (columns 5,10,15,20,25,and 30) vs the same x-axis data, I use this following piece of code,

```
plt <- ggplot() + 
  lapply(seq(5,ncol(x3),5),         
         function(x){              
           geom_line(aes(x=x3[1], y=x3[x]),                           
                     color=variable,                                
                     size=1.5) + scale_y_continuous()                                          
         }) +   xlab('x') +  ylab('y')
```

But I get error in do.call("layer"  ..
Could someone please point out what I need to modify in the above code to display the data in a proper manner along with the legend.

Thanks

Comment: you should reshape your data.frame to long format, see `reshape2::melt`.

Comment: @baptiste Once I melt the data frame `x3`, how can I reference only certain columns to be plotted like in this case, col 5,10,15,20,25, and 30.

Comment: i give my data pet names, it's easier to identify them. Numbers are cold-blooded. You can, if you need to, use `names(x3)[c(5, 10, 15, 20)]` instead and use the default names assigned by R when you created the data.frame. You might need `aes_string` if you take that route.

Comment: @baptise So i use this, but I get error in aesthetics length, `x3_m <-melt(x3, id=names(x3)[1]) ;
p <- ggplot(x3_m, aes_string(x=names(x3)[1],y= names(x3)[c(5, 10, 15, 20)]))+ 
  geom_point(aes(color = variable), size = 1)`

Comment: Your melted data, as it stands, has three columns: `names(x3)[1]`, `value`, and `variable`. So you want `ggplot(x3_m, aes(names(x3)[1], value, colour=variable)+ geom_line()`. To select specific variables from the original data, either specify them in melt() as meas.vars, or use `subset(x3_m, variable %in% names(x3)[c(5, 10, 15, 20)]))` before plotting.

Comment: @baptiste Thanks for pointing out meas.vars I am learning to use this for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `melt` to reshape your data into long format:

```
x4 <- melt(x3, id=c("x"), measure=c("t","s.1","z.2","y.3","x.4","q.4"), variable = "cols")
```

Then create your plot with:

```
ggplot(x4) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=value, color=cols), size=1) + 
  scale_y_continuous()
```

which gives:

[image]