# Referencing x axis variable from a melted data frame to plot using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2, melt

I have a data frame `df` with 10 columns such as this,

```
row.names   c(300, 400, 500, 600, 700)  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9
1   absTLM_3_4  300 -4.147782e-08   -3.360635e-08   -3.306786e-08   -3.133482e-08   -3.124207e-08   -3.056317e-08   -3.020253e-08   -2.950814e-08   -2.955155e-08
2   absTLM_4_5  400 -3.703708e-08   -3.013687e-08   -2.746570e-08   -2.627163e-08   -2.528328e-08   -2.457543e-08   -2.437666e-08   -2.412295e-08   -2.358447e-08
3   absTLM_5_6  500 -3.575756e-08   -2.694028e-08   -2.457341e-08   -2.331162e-08   -2.262283e-08   -2.180886e-08   -2.104917e-08   -2.101946e-08   -2.081650e-08
4   absTLM_6_7  600 -2.454283e-08   -2.152165e-08   -1.967477e-08   -1.885213e-08   -1.835989e-08   -1.814608e-08   -1.806438e-08   -1.785795e-08   -1.784158e-08
5   absTLM_7_8  700 -2.317125e-10   -1.029456e-08   -1.076342e-08   -1.365264e-08   -1.378578e-08   -1.457421e-08   -1.463740e-08   -1.480280e-08   -1.515121e-0
```

Now I would like to plot column 1 in the x-axis versus columns 2,5,6, and 8 in the y-axis. For doing this I use the following piece of code,

```
x4 <- melt(df, id=names(df)[1], measure=names(df)[c(2, 5, 6, 8)], variable = "cols")
plt <- ggplot(x4) +
        geom_line(aes(x=x,y= value, color=cols), size=1) +
        labs(x = "x", y = "y")
```

When I call the plot object `plt` I get an **Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found**.
Could someone kindly point out what I should change here to display the plot correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no column named `x` in `X4`. See `head(x4)` and adjust your `geom_line(aes())` accordingly.

Comment: It looks like the column is called `X1`, not `x`.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen it seems column header of the first column which I need is named `c(300, 400, 500, 600, 700)` , now when I use `plt <- ggplot(x4) +
    geom_line(aes(x=c(300, 400, 500, 600, 700),y= value, color=cols), size=1) +
    labs(x = "x", y = "y")` I still get an error such as, Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:c(300, 400, 500, 600, 700)

Comment: I think you should just rename the columns and use a typical style (no space in column names only `_` or `.`). `colnames(df)[1] <- "x"` and perhaps your original code will work. Could you provide us with `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: [yep, again, consider renaming your columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308879/plotting-multiple-data-in-a-data-frame-at-fixed-column-intervals-with-correspond#comment32117134_21308879)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your column names are buggered. Try this:

```
x4 <- melt(df, id=names(df)[1], measure=names(df)[c(2, 5, 6, 8)], variable = "cols")
colnames(x4)[1] <- "x"
plt <- ggplot(x4) +
        geom_line(aes(x=x,y= value, color=cols), size=1) +
        labs(x = "x", y = "y")
```

Comment: Yes, you were right. After changing the column header name it works! Thanks for your useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the following piece of code did not correctly plot the data was due to the column header name `c(300, 400, 500, 600, 700)` which was name of the first column in the data frame `df`.

```
x4 <- melt(df, id=names(df)[1], measure=names(df)[c(2, 5, 6, 8)], variable = "cols")
plt <- ggplot(x4) +
        geom_line(aes(x=x,y= value, color=cols), size=1) +
        labs(x = "x", y = "y")
```

So the column header name  of `df` had to be changed first, according to the suggestion by Brandon Bertelsen, the column header name of `c(300, 400, 500, 600, 700)` was changed to `x` by the following line of code,

```
colnames(df)[1] <- "x"
```

Once the column header name is changed, then the data frame can be melted after which the plotting works correctly,

```
x4 <- melt(df, id=names(df)[1], measure=names(df)[c(2, 5, 6, 8)], variable = "cols")
plt <- ggplot(x4) +
        geom_point(aes(x=x,y= value, color=cols), size=2) +
        labs(x = "x", y = "y")
```

So the plot `plt` looks like this,

[image]