# Plotting multiple variable in dot plot using ggplot2 and melting

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a CSV which has following data:

```
 Hybrid    ON   OFF Model
1  1.022 1.033 0.939   283
2  0.988 1.016 1.068   283
3  1.012 0.958 1.872   283
4  1.073 5.476 0.907   283
5  1.054 0.952 0.902   283
6  0.992 0.941 0.908   283
```

I am trying to create a dot plot with something like this image.

[image]

Basically red green and blue are hybrid, on and off respectively, and on x-axis they are grouped on the 'Model'. I am familiar with creating simple plots using plot() but I have been reading some tutorial that this could be achieved using ggplot and melt..which looks a bit advanced. Appreciate if someone can provide some indicators. I have tried to create levels for different config after loading the csv:

```
load <- read.csv("combined_temp.csv", sep="," , header=TRUE)    

df <- data.frame(Config= rep(c("Hybrid", "ON", "OFF")))
```

I want use ggplot after this but not sure how to do that.. even not sure if I am doing the replication right. Sorry I am extremely new to R.

Comment: For some inspiration on a compareble problem, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21309765/2204410)

Comment: I am sure there is a much simpler way to solve this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to reshape your data into long format, after that you can make such a plot easily with `ggplot2`:

```
library(reshape2)
dfl <- melt(df, id = "Model")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfl, aes(x = factor(Model), y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = variable), shape = 1, size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  theme_bw()
```

this results in the following plot:

[image]

---

For illustrative reasons, I have expanded and changed the data.

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(Hybrid = c(1.022, 0.988, 1.012, 1.073, 1.054, 0.992, 2.022, 1.988, 2.012, 2.073, 2.054, 1.992), 
                     ON = c(1.033, 1.016, 0.958, 3.476, 0.952, 0.941, 2.033, 2.016, 1.958, 3.476, 1.952, 1.941),
                     OFF = c(0.939, 1.068, 1.872, 0.907, 0.902, 0.908, 2.939, 1.068, 1.872, 2.907, 2.902, 2.908),
                     Model = c(283L, 283L, 283L, 283L, 283L, 283L, 382L, 382L, 382L, 382L, 382L, 382L)),
                .Names = c("Hybrid", "ON", "OFF", "Model"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks. Why do we need to use position_dodge? I took a similar approach in my solution but used  facet to group the plot based on Model. Since using facet achieves the same purpose, what is the benefit of using position_dodge vs facet?

Comment: The benefit of using `position_dodge` is that you can plot the different models in one plot. However, when you have a lot of Models, it's indeed better to use facets.